# Translate recursive method to formula

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

This query might be simple for you guys but I don't really  know why I am scratching my head from last 2 hrs.

Below is the simple code which loops through same method for 99 times and it will give 5050 as result.

```
class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        test test1 = new test();
        System.out.println(test1.xyz(100));           
    } 
    public int xyz(int num) {
        if(num ==1) {
           return 1;        
        }  
        else {
           return(xyz(num-1) + num);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how to solve this code  manually. What equation do I need to use?

Comment: The 5050 is correct for your code. What do you want your program to do ?

Comment: i want to know what equation/formula  we need to use if we want to calculate it manually

Answer (score 3):

What is happening in your recursive function `xyz()` is summing up `100 to 1`.

```
100 + 99 + 98 + .... + 1
```

Which means sum up the first `nth` natural number! So you can use a simple [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) to find the result:

```
n(n + 1) / 2
```

in program:

```
n = input;
sum = n(n + 1) / 2
```

Or, if you want to loop for finding the sum, you can do this:

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= input; i++)
    sum += i; // sum = sum + i
```

Answer (score 1):

The equation is actually `f(n) = f(n-1) + n` and `f(n)=1` for `n=1`. This is actually sum of all the numbers and for `n=100` the result is `(100*101)/2 = 5050` as the sum of natural numbers is: `n(n+1) / 2`. The method is recursive.

If you want an iterative version then for that you need to use a loop. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<=100; i++) {
            result = result + i;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What your program does is to add all the numbers from 1 to num. In every iteration you add num-1 to num, so it does like "100 + 99 + 98 + 97 ..."

The equation you search for is `(N(N + 1))/2`.

Answer (score 0):

When you first call `test1.xyz(100)` it call `xyz()` method with argument **100**. Then it calls `return(xyz(num-1) + num);` meas it calls `xyz(99)` and adds **100** in it. Because `xyz(99)` is not yet evaluated so it is pushed in stack. In call of `xyz(99)`, it calls `return(xyz(num-1) + num);` meas it calls `xyz(98)` and adds `99` in it. Because `xyz(99)` is not yet evaluated so it is pushed in stack. It keeps pusing calls of `xyz()` in stack till you call `xyz(1)+2`. `xyz(1)` returns **1** as per code. So `xyz(1)+2`  statement returns **3** to the call `xyz(2)`. Now compiler pop the call which are stackd and at the end it returns the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Iterative Method" or "Substitution Method" for solve this. These methods are using for calculate the time complexity, but it works for your purpose too.

Basically, you write your method as a mathematic function.

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + n , n > 1
T(n) = 1          , n = 1
```

When you do that, you can iterate the function for i steps, which is a random number. For more information you can look this page:

[Analysis of Algorithm - geeksforgeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-algorithm-set-4-master-method-solving-recurrences/)